# Dealing with node language when manually updating node

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to manually update a node and I'm not sure how the language works.

The node is in English, so `$node->language = 'en';`

However, all my fields data are organized like this in the node:

```
$node->field_name['und'][0]['value']
```

I thought `'und'` means "language undefined", so shouldn't it be `'en'` instead?

I'm trying to automate the process so is it safe to assume fields will always use `'und'` in nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - it is safe to assume this. The locale module will deal with this by setting it to the language code of the default language, ex 'en'.

Citing from: http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#drupal_language_none

```
In Drupal 7, the LANGUAGE_NONE constant should be used for nodes or other items that do not have a specific language associated with it.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get field values without use LANGUAGE_NONE.

```
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$value = $field_items[0]['value'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of specifying a language, I prefer to just use `entity_metadata_wrapper()`.

For example:

```
$node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', SOME_NODE_ID);
$value = $node->field_something->value(); // returns field value
$node->field_something->set('new value'); // sets field value
$node->save();
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers

Comment: Hey hey, welcome to DA. Nice snippet. But I don't actually see how this answers OP's problem?

Comment: It's more of a different way to solve the root problem so that the actual question becomes a moot point.